# Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views Having Errors

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am creating Android tab layout with swipeable views but I am getting some errors. I dont know how to solve these errors.

Code-

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Types extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    ImageView left, right;
    Intent objIntent;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = { "type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5", "type6", "type7", "type8" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.types);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        objIntent = new Intent(Types.this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        objIntent = new Intent(Types.this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent); 
        startActivity(new Intent (Types.this, MainActivity.class));  
        finish();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        objIntent = new Intent(Types.this, PlayAudio.class);
        startService(objIntent);
    }

}
```

Logcat-

```
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191): at com.info.abc.Types.onCreate(Types.java:38)
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-29 01:45:36.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1191):     ... 11 more
```

This is line 38:

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Import Files-

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

Comment: try actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); and also if your activity does not have a title bar the method getActionBar() can return null.

Comment: I already try by setting it to true but still same error.

Comment: @JohnR: are you testing it in a lower version device?

Comment: I changed the minSDK value to API 11 but still same error.

Comment: And I am also try to run it on my device. But app stop working.

Comment: I have installed support library to support lower API but still not working.

Comment: @JohnR: post your import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, I am assuming that you are testing the app in a lower version (below API 11) device.Thats why you are getting the exception.`ActionBar` is introduced in API level 11. Now to make it work, you got 2 following ways,

1.Change your min SDK value to API 11.

2.Use `android-support-v7-appcompat` library which supports `ActionBar` from API level 7.

- To use `ActionBarCompat`, your activity should extend `ActionBarActivity`.
- change your activity theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

For more information, visit the following  site ,
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: I have installed support library to support lower API but still not working.

Comment: @JohnR: did you added `android-support-v7-appcompat` ?

Comment: Yes I am importing android.support.v7.app.ActionBar  in my activity.

Comment: I marked 2 things in your code.you can't use `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` in below API 11 and you have to extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity `.

Comment: When i extending ActionBarActivity I am getting error on most of the lines.

Comment: @JohnR: To use `ActionBarCompat`, you must extend `ActionBarActivity`.I would like to suggest you to read the developer blog from the link that I have given to get a clear idea.

Comment: and it is necessary to create theme? If yes in which activity to create it?

Comment: @JohnR: if you add `ActionBarCompat` as a library project, then no necessary to create theme.This library already contains all the themes.

Answer (score 1):

If your activity does not have a `title bar` the method `getActionBar()` can return null.

You have two options to fix this:

1. Add `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before `setContentView`
2. In your `Manifest` specify a Theme that supports `ActionBar`

Also make sure that you are targeting the right android version e.g. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />`

Further Infromation go to this [Link.](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html)

Comment: I have installed support library to support lower API but still not working.